# htaccess causes browser to keep redirecting with a forward slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having issues with my htaccess file set up for a website. The problem is when I access a specific location link with no forward slash:

example.com/location/city

Then it redirects to:

example.com/location///////

And keeps rewriting adding a forward slash each time.

This only happens when I remove the forward slash from the end. If the forward slash is there, the page loads in fine. All other pages on the site are working fine.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#####################################################
# Rewrite specific pages - listings
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+listings\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)packageType=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&packageTypeSub=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images|email|email-newsletter|login|logout|pml|search|download_pdf|mywebtool|mywebtool_data|mywebtool-enquiries|phpmyadmin|test) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ listings.php?packageType=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images|email|email-newsletter|login|logout|pml|search|download_pdf|mywebtool|mywebtool_data|mywebtool-enquiries|phpmyadmin|test) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ listings.php?packageType=$1&packageTypeSub=$2 [L,QSA] 


#####################################################
# Rewrite specific pages - location (used for all location except provinceState)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+location\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)place=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&packageType=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ location/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images|email|email-newsletter|login|logout|pml|search|download_pdf|mywebtool|mywebtool_data|mywebtool-enquiries|phpmyadmin|test) [NC]
RewriteRule ^location/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ location.php?place=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rewrite specific pages - location (provinceState)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+location\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)provinceState=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&packageType=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ location/provinceState-%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images|email|email-newsletter|login|logout|pml|search|download_pdf|mywebtool|mywebtool_data|mywebtool-enquiries|phpmyadmin|test) [NC]
RewriteRule ^location/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ location.php?provinceState=$1 [L,QSA]

# Allow place, packageType and packageTypeSub (for dropdowns)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+location\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)place=([^&]+)&packageType=([^&\s]+)&packageTypeSub=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ location/%1/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images|email|email-newsletter|login|logout|pml|search|download_pdf|mywebtool|mywebtool_data|mywebtool-enquiries|phpmyadmin|test) [NC]
RewriteRule ^location/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ location.php?place=$1&packageType=$2&packageTypeSub=$3 [L,QSA]

# Allow place, packageType and packageTypeSub (for dropdowns provinceState)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+location\.php\? [NC]   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)provinceState=([^&]+)&packageType=([^&\s]+)&packageTypeSub=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ location/provinceState-%1/%2/%3/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(upload-images|email|email-newsletter|login|logout|pml|search|download_pdf|mywebtool|mywebtool_data|mywebtool-enquiries|phpmyadmin|test) [NC]
RewriteRule ^location/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ location.php?provinceState=$1&packageType=$2&packageTypeSub=$3 [L,QSA]


#####################################################
# All other pages
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Location of 404 page if errors
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404-not-found

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

The first part is for the listings pages, and the second part for the location page. For some reason the location link is passing in to the listings part and causing the issue. If I disable the listings part / section of code the problem goes away.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Very strange indeed. I'm assuming that it adds an extra forward slash every time you redirect to another page. A fix for this is to just force the trailing slash(s) to not appear.

Use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.